# Array a float c++

Tags: c++

Como puedo pasar los valores de un array char a una variable tipo float
->así lo tengo declarado: char numero[20];
->lee números de este tipo: 4.5678
pero necesito hacer operaciones con el numero que se encuentra en el char y necesito que los valores pasen a una variable tipo float

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo sobre [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que tu problema debe ser reproducible y debes de mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora, de lo contrario puedes causar la impresión de querer que te hagan la tarea.

Answer (score 1):

No lo metas en una formación de caracteres, lee directamente el `float`?

```
float numero;
std::cin >> numero;
```

Pero si no tienes más remedio, pasa los datos a un flujo de texto y el flujo de texto a un `float`:

```
char numero[20] = "4.5678";
std::stringstream ss{numero};
float numero_coma_flotante;
ss >> numero_coma_flotante;
```

O si eso te parece engorroso, usa `std::from_chars`:

```
char numero[20] = "4.5678";
float numero_coma_flotante;
std::from_chars(std::begin(numero), std::end(numero), numero_coma_flotante);
```